# How to check real consuption of memory in task manager

Tags: windows, memory, resources

on my notebook with 32 gb ram I can see only partially how many GB individual processes takes. This does not correspond at all to what is in the 12 gb graph vs what is in the detail. Is there any way to find out what really takes up so many GB of ram?
Thank you
[image]
[image]

Comment: I learned recently that the task manager shows two aspects of RAM usage. The detailed view shows how much RAM processes are **using**. The graph shows how much RAM processes have **reserved** for their use. The example I can best use is the game Overwatch, which reserved itself 10GB but only used about 4-6. The standard Task Manager doesn't make this clear, and third party software will give a better understanding.

Comment: The graph absolutely does show active memory, not committed memory. // What I can see on the screenshots already adds up to more than 5 GiB. Who knows how many other 100-MB-ish processes follow. They do add up, a lot. Nevertheless, you are not really interested in per-process use, but rather per-application use. Teams, Edge, Visual Studio etc all consist of multiple processes.

Comment: I've observed what I described in my first comment, but my anecdotal experience doesn't necessarily count :)

Comment: "Is there any way to find out what really takes up so many GB of ram?" - It's easier to just use a tool like RAMMAP.  You screenshot doesn't include the memory services are using.